# To find $n$ such that the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ has three consecutive coefficients $p,q,r$ that satisfy $p:q:r = 1:7:35$.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics

To find $n$ such that the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ has three consecutive coefficients $p,q,r$ that satisfy $$p:q:r = 1:7:35$$

---

My work:

Suppose the consecutive coefficients are $\binom{n}{k-1}, \binom{n}{k}$ and $\binom{n}{k+1}$. Then we have

$$\dfrac{\binom{n}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{k}{n-k+1}= \frac17$$ and

$$\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{n}{k+1}} = \frac{k+1}{n-k}= \frac{7}{35}= \frac15$$

Cross multiplying we have $7k = n-k+1 \implies n = 8k-1$ and $5k+5=n-k \implies n = 6k+5$.

Thus $8k-1=6k+5 \implies k = 3$ and hence $n = 23$.

---

Is my argument fine?

Comment: Your arguments and your result are correct.

Comment: You can plug in and check.  For the second, here is an [Alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%2823+choose+4%29%2F%2823+choose+3%29)

Comment: Or [another](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+%281%2Bx%29%5E23) where $1771/253=7$ and $8855/253=35$

Comment: Alternatively, using that $\,\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\implies \frac{a}{a+b}=\frac{c}{c+d}\,$ you get $\,\frac{k}{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+7}\,$ and $\,\frac{k+1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+5}\,$, then subtracting the two $\,\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}\,$.